# How do I keep document.title updated in React app?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, react-router

Since React doesn't have any builtin way to manage `document.title`, I used to set it inside `componentDidMount` of my route handlers.

However now I need to amend the title based on `state` fetched asynchronously. I started putting assingments into `componentDidUpdate`, but every now and then I forget to put `document.title` assignment into some pages, and previous title sticks around until I finally notice it.

Ideally I'd like a way to express `document.title` declaratively, without having to assign it.   Some kind of “fake” component would probably be most convenient, given that I want to be able to specify the document title at several nesting levels:

- On top level (the default title);
- On page level (for some of the pages, but not all);
- Sometimes, on inner component level (e.g. user typing into a field).

Additional requirements:

- Title specified in child should override title specified by parent;
- Reliable (guarantees cleanup on route change);
- Should not emit any DOM (i.e. no hacks with component returning `<noscript>`);
- I'm using react-router but it's better if this component works with other routers too.

Anything I can use?

Comment: What's wrong just having `document.title = this.state.documentTitle` in your render function?  Or doing something similar with a check for changes first.

Comment: @Mike: First, you shouldn't do that in `render`, it is supposed to have no side effects. You probably mean `componentDidUpdate`. Well, as the app grows it becomes harder to keep `document.title` consistent if you want it to be present for some screens, but use some default title for others. Only takes one page to forget specify the title, and it gets stale.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I wrote [**react-document-title**](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title) just for that.

It provides a declarative way to specify `document.title` in a single-page app.
If you want to get title on server after rendering components to string, call `DocumentTitle.rewind()`.

### Features

- Does not emit DOM, not even a `<noscript>`;
- Like a normal React compoment, can use its parent's `props` and `state`;
- Can be defined in many places throughout the application;
- Supports arbitrary levels of nesting, so you can define app-wide and page-specific titles;
- Works on client and server.

### Example

Assuming you use something like [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router):

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    // Use "My Web App" if no child overrides this
    return (
      <DocumentTitle title='My Web App'>
        <this.props.activeRouteHandler />
      </DocumentTitle>
    );
  }
});

var HomePage = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    // Use "Home" while this component is mounted
    return (
      <DocumentTitle title='Home'>
        <h1>Home, sweet home.</h1>
      </DocumentTitle>
    );
  }
});

var NewArticlePage = React.createClass({
  mixins: [LinkStateMixin],

  render: function () {
    // Update using value from state while this component is mounted
    return (
      <DocumentTitle title={this.state.title || 'Untitled'}>
        <div>
          <h1>New Article</h1>
          <input valueLink={this.linkState('title')} />
        </div>
      </DocumentTitle>
    );
  }
});
```

### Source

I keep track of mounted instances and only use `title` given to the top `DocumentTitle` in the mounted instance stack whenever it updates, gets mounted or unmounted. On server, `componentWillMount` fires but we won't get `didMount` or `willUnmount`, so we introduce `DocumentTitle.rewind()` that returns a string and destroys state to prepare for next request.

```
var DocumentTitle = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    title: PropTypes.string
  },

  statics: {
    mountedInstances: [],

    rewind: function () {
      var activeInstance = DocumentTitle.getActiveInstance();
      DocumentTitle.mountedInstances.splice(0);

      if (activeInstance) {
        return activeInstance.props.title;
      }
    },

    getActiveInstance: function () {
      var length = DocumentTitle.mountedInstances.length;
      if (length > 0) {
        return DocumentTitle.mountedInstances[length - 1];
      }
    },

    updateDocumentTitle: function () {
      if (typeof document === 'undefined') {
        return;
      }

      var activeInstance = DocumentTitle.getActiveInstance();
      if (activeInstance) {
        document.title = activeInstance.props.title;
      }
    }
  },

  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
      title: ''
    };
  },

  isActive: function () {
    return this === DocumentTitle.getActiveInstance();
  },

  componentWillMount: function () {
    DocumentTitle.mountedInstances.push(this);
    DocumentTitle.updateDocumentTitle();
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps) {
    if (this.isActive() && prevProps.title !== this.props.title) {
      DocumentTitle.updateDocumentTitle();
    }
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    var index = DocumentTitle.mountedInstances.indexOf(this);
    DocumentTitle.mountedInstances.splice(index, 1);
    DocumentTitle.updateDocumentTitle();
  },

  render: function () {
    if (this.props.children) {
      return Children.only(this.props.children);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
});

module.exports = DocumentTitle;
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, might you suggest another solution that solves this problem?

Comment: Is this npm package still good to be used for just setting doc title? I am using React 15.1.0.

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at the NFL's [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

Comment: react-helmet is awesome!

Answer (score 7):

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    document.title = this.props.title;
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and then `<Layout title="My Title"/>` that easy!

Answer (score 4):

Try [react-frozenhead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-frozenhead), it's actually more sophisticated than react-document-title - it allows us change title, description and anything else in  section.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, 3 years have gone! ;-)
If you want to manipulate other page headers than title (like description, canonical, etc.), [react-document-meta](https://github.com/kodyl/react-document-meta) NPM dependency could be a good thing to use.